# How do I delete the line above and below the matching line using regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a document where the matching line is `[]`

**For above:**

Whenever the matching line is found, the line above that should be deleted. In this case `## mentions` should be deleted.

```
## mentions
[]
```

**For below:**

Whenever the matching line is found, the line below that should be deleted. In this case `## mentions` should be deleted.

```
[]
## mentions
```

How to achieve this using regex?

Edit: I am using VSCode regex.

Comment: What programming language / library / system are you using?

Comment: @AndreasT VSCode

Comment: What if there is a line above and below? Or are you asking two questions?

Comment: Above = just the single line above the matching line. If there are multiple lines above the matching line, only select the first line above the matching one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.*\n(?=\[\])` by nothing for above. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/6c7Zd2/1)

Replace `(?<=(\[\]))\n.*` by nothing for below. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/T5cBwN/1)

### Explanation for above

```
.*       Match all characters appearing 0 to N times
\n       Match a newline character
(?=\[\]) Make sure that [] is found just after the newline character
```

### Explanation for below

```
(?<=(\[\])) Make sure our target is on the line before
\n          Match a newline character
.*          Match all characters appearing 0 to N times
```

### Matching `[]` as group

To match `[]` as a group, simply enclose it with paranthesis like hereunder

```
.*\n(?=(\[\]))
```

Comment: This works! Can you also please make an edit to include the regex for selecting line "below" the matching line?

I am accepting it as soon as SO allows.

Comment: @JiayounoKim you mean to match it as group?

Comment: For example, if the text is:
[]
## mentions

then ## mentions should be selected as its the line below.

And yes, if it's not much trouble please show group as well. That would be all. Thank you!

Comment: OK I understand it

Comment: @JiayounoKim should be OK now?

Comment: This "below" regex you did works on regex101 website but on VSCode, it shows error: Lone qualifier bracket!?

Comment: I'll test @JiayounoKim and I'll let you know

Comment: @JiayounoKim Ok I corrected it for VSCode, they don't like when you don't escape brackets

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.